# using Display.getDefault().syncexec() inside getHoverInfo() of org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.hover.IJavaEditorTextHover

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, hover, thread-safety, synchronization

I need a Thread to execute some work inside the method getHoverInfo() of IJavaEditorTextHover. But before i return anything on this method, i need the thread to complete it´s work.

I have tried to use a while() to wait for the thread like this:

But still the method getHoverInfo() is not returning null or any other string. I need to return some especific strings on this method and i need the thread to obtain it.

What can i do? How can i wait for the Thread to finish it´s work?

//NEW INFORMATION

I have to initiate a Thread on the method getHoverInfo and i need the rest of my code to be executed only when the thread ends it´s job.
The thread can only run on asyncexec because if it runs on syncexec, getHoverInfo will never return anything
I cannot use anything like Thread.sleep or a while() inside getHoverInfo. I tried and getHoverInfo() never returns anything(what i mean is: the javadoc is never showed even though the method returns null, for example)
My code is like below:

public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion) {
        if (hoverRegion != null) {

```
            /*comeca novo */
        ThreadGetHoverInfoExtensaoMostraExcecoes thread = new ThreadGetHoverInfoExtensaoMostraExcecoes();
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(thread);

            /*termina novo */

            while(thread.endedJob == false)
            {
                //wait
            }
               return thread.getSomething();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ? so people can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to wait for the thread to finish try [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

However, its generally unwise to manage the threading yourself, try using an executor and submit the work you need as a [future task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) that you can manage independently of the thread.

If you are trying to prevent Swing from blocking while you are doing some long running task, you need to move your logic out of the event thread, perform the work, and then call back into the event thread once you are finished.  Here is an example:

```
public static final Executor singleThreadedExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );

public void methodOnUIThread()
{
    //Do normal callback stuff here
    ...

    //Submit the threaded long running task, and return out of this method
    singleThreadedExecutor.execute( new LongRunningWorkTask() );
}

private static class LongRunningWorkTask implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //todo do something long here

        //Call back into the UI thread with an update
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //todo: Update the UI thread here, now that the long running task is done
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need to use Display.getDefault().syncexec() because my thread will work with IJavaProject and stuff. If i don´t use syncexec or asyncexec, the thread will obtain a null pointer exception

Comment: Without code there is not much more I can do to help.  A thread would only get an NPE if it was trying to deference an object that you hadn't initialized, I'm not sure what using the display sync has to do with it.

Comment: `syncExec` does not run a thread, it executes code in the existing user interface thread and returns only after that is done. It should not be used to run long running code as it will block the UI.

Comment: If you are trying not to block the UI thread, you can't have the method wait for the thread to finish.  Editing answer.